# Why does OR operator have so high priority

Tags: javascript, syntax

I wonder why the OR operator has higher priority than most operators, forcing parentheses.

```
 if (!player.slowTimeAcive || frameCount % 2 === 0) {
    // framecount evaluated as truethy
 }    

 if (!player.slowTimeAcive || (frameCount % 2 === 0)) {
    // forced parentheses
 }
```

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. The `||` operator [has lower precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) then all of the other operators in your expression (and lower than most other operators too). The parentheses shouldn't make any difference in that example.

Comment: Because the people who designed the language made it that way. How does speculating about why it was done change anything? It will still have the same priority.

Comment: I made a typo ...

Comment: Yes, but please don't remove relevant parts of the question (i.e. the entire question). You can delete your question instead.

Comment: @AaditMShah or just fix the typo. No reason to spam another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` in your example will not cause you to require parenthesis.

You can read about the precedence of all operators in JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

You should use parenthesis to increase readability, or to bring a lower priority operator above a higher priority one, for example:

```
 var a = 10;
 var b = false;
 var c = 9;
 (a||b) >= c
 //evaluates to true
```

As compared to:

```
var a = 10;
var b = false;
var c = 9;
a||b >= c
//evaluates to 10
```